# Asymmetrical Grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I see native android has asymmetrical grid [options](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView).

But I am looking for something similar in Xamarin, forms specifically. Can't seem to find anything. Am I stuck resolving this need with a relative layout? As the grid layout does not support this from what I can tell. Any solutions people have seen out there before I spend my night on making something like this.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a normal grid with merge cols and merge rows support. I don't code in xamarin, but I would have thought this was basic grid functionality.

Comment: It's good to see people coding up a Windows Phone UI on Android. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in Xamarin Forms using the `Grid` layout. Set up your grid to have as many rows and columns as you would like and then add the `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` properties on the child views.

You will achieve the same effect.

More info - [Present views in grids.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/)

Comment: Jesus... I have been staring at my screen too long. Thanks, ya I just need to make more columns and rows using the span feature to give the effect I need.